# How to encrypt single column in sqlite database in my Python Flask app?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want one column in my sqlite database to be encrypted but still visible to my Flask app. When I use the solution below - my Flask app is able to see data in the encrypted column, but when I open the database I see that the data is encrypted.

But I'm not sure if my solution is secure to host publicly on pythonanywhere.com. What are the vulnerabilities that I face. Is it safe to keep my 'key' in the code? This is my code below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from sqlalchemy_utils import EncryptedType

key = "my_encryption_key_here"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hello'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

class Rx(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sx_string = db.Column(EncryptedType(db.String, key), nullable=True, unique=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest putting it into a separate file, which is explicitly ignored in your `.gitignore` file, and then importing it from there.  Alternatively, you could use a `.env` file containing environment variables that you could load in (there's a help page on the PythonAnywhere website that explains how to do that, just search the front page for "environment".

The reason is that if it's mixed in with the rest of your code, if you have your code in a git repo stored on GitHub or something similar, your encryption key will be on that service -- so in the event of a breach of that service, or if you accidentally make the repo public or something like that, your key will be leaked.